# Return multiple instances from an object in python

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization

This question has no doubt been asked before, but I am not entirely sure how to search for it (since I do not know what it is called). So apologies in advance.

Alas, my problem is that I have a huge amount of objects

```
for i in range(1000):
    M = subParts[0].get(parts['thing'][i])
```

Each `M` is an object that contains a lot of info about this model, now my job is to call four separate functions on this object, so that those functions can return four simple numbers as so:

```
for i in range(1000):
    M = subParts[0].get(parts['thing'][i])
    M.getItem1()
    M.getItem2()
    M.getItem3()
    M.getItem4()
```

each of which returns a number, e.g.

```
4.5
5.7
3.7
2.9
```

My question is thus, what is an efficient way to do this? The above is very ugly but works, but there must be more efficient methods. Upon which I would just like to store the whole lot in a dictionary as so

```
myDict = { 0 : [4.5,5.7,3.7,2.9], ... , 999 : [2.5,3.7,5.7,2.9] }
```

Thanks.

Comment: A dictionary whose keys are sequential numbers starting from `0` is essentially just a list.

Comment: I notice you retrieve `subParts[0]` and `parts['thing']` every iteration, It might make sense to store those ahead of time (`relevant_part = parts["thing"]`) would simplify that statement and reduce repetitive lookups.

Comment: actually, if `parts['thing']` is a (ordered) sequence you could do `for M in map(subParts[0].get, parts["thing"]):` to iterate over all the `M` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `parts['thing']` is an ordered sequence that can be iterated over, you can use `map` to call `subParts[0].get` on each element of `parts['thing']` so iterating over each `M` object could be done like this:

```
for M in map(subParts[0].get, parts['thing']):
    ...
```

Note that this will return a list in python 2 so using `itertools.imap` would be preferable.

To put it into dict comprehension you would just do:

```
stuff = {i:[M.getItem1(),
            M.getItem2(),
            M.getItem3(),
            M.getItem4()]
         for i,M in enumerate(map(subParts[0].get, parts['thing']))}
```

Comment: The `from operator import attrgetter` approach seemed more elegant? How come that is not advisable?

Comment: it retrieves `M.getItem1` bound method but _doesn't call it_, attrgetter wasn't meant for that so adding that step wouldn't be easy.

Comment: using `attrgetter` would have been perfect if you were retrieving attributes like `M.Item1` but getting a tuple of bound methods wouldn't have helped in this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

```
def getdata(m):
    return [m.getItem1(), m.getItem2(), m.getItem3(), m.getItem4()]

myDict = {i: getdata(subParts[0].get(parts['thing'][i])) for i in range(1000)}
```